# Не могу открыть файл(C++)

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

Не получается открыть файл в программе. Уже открывал и как в языке Си,через адрес файла указывал, по разному вообщем. Сам файл находиться в папке проекта.
Что могло пойти не так?

```
fstream fin("G:\\03.04");  
if (!fin.is_open())
{
    cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Файл открыт!" << endl;

}
```

Comment: Если файл в папке проекта, то зачем пытаться открыть из корня диска?

Answer (score 0):

Странный путь к файлу, т.е. файл 03 с расширением 04 лежит в корне диска G, там же и расположен проект?
Попробуйте скопировать файл непосредственно к скомпилированному файлу. В **Visual Studio** это обычно папка "Debug" (если вы работаете в Debug режиме).
Убедитесь, что файл имеет именно такое имя.
Если вы разрабатываете в **DevCpp**, то просто можно положить файл к скомпилированному файлу.

Когда файл лежит вместе со скомпилированным .exe файлом, то путь к файлу для потока fstream может быть и относительный, т.е. просто `fstream fin("03.04");`